# What is the difference between asynchronous and synchronous HTTP request?

Tags: webserver

What is the difference between **asynchronous** and **synchronous** HTTP request?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101758/performance-difference-between-synchronous-http-handler-and-asynchronous-http-ha

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You may want to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on the types of questions to ask here. Specific programming questions with code examples.  General questions such as this are better suited to <insert Search engine here>  Spend a bit of time researching the question and if you can truely find no answer then ask but show some work on your part, don't expect the community here to help you if you're not willing to help yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining synchronous vs. asynchronous in web applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971301/determining-synchronous-vs-asynchronous-in-web-applications)

Answer (score 70):

**Synchronous**:
A synchronous request blocks the client until operation completes. In such case, javascript engine of the browser is blocked.

**Asynchronous**
An asynchronous request doesn’t block the client i.e. browser is responsive. At that time, user can perform another operations also. In such case, javascript engine of the browser is not blocked.

Comment: Synchronous / Asynchronous communication has nothing to do with application waiting or not for resources. Synchronous communication is when communication looks like ping-pong one request and one response in that particular order. Asynchronous communication is when there could be multiple requests and responses could return in random order.

Comment: I agree. A blocking call is only one factor in the entire scenario and it is a client-side issue. The other side of the equation is the server-side, which has to be re-architected to accommodate this pattern.

Comment: This answer has > 50 thumbs up, and expresses something reasonable. However, @Logman's comment - as much reasonable as the answer - claims the answer is plainly wrong. This is highly misleading for the reader. I have flagged the question for moderator intervention, but it was rejected.

Answer (score 11):

Check out [Determining synchronous vs. asynchronous in web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971301/determining-synchronous-vs-asynchronous-in-web-applications) for previous discussion. In short:

> Asynchronous APIs do not block. Every synchronous call waits and blocks for your results to > come back. This is just a sleeping thread and wasted computation.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous APIs do not block. Every synchronous call waits and blocks for your results to come back. This is just a sleeping thread and wasted computation.

If you need something to happen, send an asynchronous request and do further computation when the request returns. This means your thread sits idle and can pick up other work.

Asynchronous requests is the way to scale to thousands of concurrent users.

Answer (score 0):

Sachin Gandhwani's answer is very well explained in simple words. In case you are still not convinced with the difference of asynchronous HTTP request and synchronous HTTP request, you can read this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: links are not permanent so try to post the necessary solution for the query.

Answer (score 0):

A synchronous client constructs an HTTP structure, sends a request, and waits for a response. An asynchronous client constructs an HTTP structure, sends a request, and moves on. In this case, the client is notified when the response arrives. The original thread, or another thread, can then process the response. Although asynchronous behavior can result in faster overall execution, synchronous behavior might be preferred in certain cases where more simplified code is necessary.