# Error in displaying JSON in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

On calling an API , got a response, stored it in a variable "items" and it is getting displayed on console also. When i access items.data[0].id, it is getting displayed in console but when i try to display same thing in render method, error is coming that :-

```
TypeError : cannot read property 0 of undefined.
```

I am calling the API call in ComponentWillMount() function in react.

Comment: You get that error because `items.data` does not exist, can you post some more code? console.log() your response, what is it's exact shape?

Comment: Can you provide a code example and the structure of the response you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is enough context here to answer your question.  Can you provide an example?  In the meantime, I'll still try to help you.

I am not sure if your request is [synchronous or asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715380/what-is-difference-between-asynchronous-http-request-and-synchronous-http-reques).  Looking at your error, you are probably making an asynchronous request.  When the first `render()` is called, `items` hasn't resolved yet.  Therefore, `item.data` is `undefined`, which is the cause of your error.

A solution is to initialize the `data` property of `this.state.item` to an empty array `[]`, that way your not calling the index operator of an undefined object.