# HTTP Synchronous nature

Tags: ajax, http, synchronous

I have read that HTTP is a synchronous protocol. Client sends a request and wait for a response. Client has wait for the first response before sending the next request. Ajax uses HTTP protocol but is asynchronous in contrast. I also read that
Synchronous request **blocks** the client until operation complete from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715380/what-is-difference-between-asynchronous-http-request-and-synchronous-http-reques). I am confused and my quesetion are:

1. what is definition of synchronous when talking about HTTP Protocol?
2. Does synchronous associated with **blocking?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTTP as a protocol is synchronous. You send a request, you wait for a response. As opposed to other protocols where you can send data in rapid succession over the same connection without waiting for a response to your previous data. Note that [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) is more along those lines actually.

Having said that, you can send multiple independent HTTP requests in parallel over separate connections. There's no "global" lock for HTTP requests, it's just a single HTTP request/response *per open connection.* (And again, HTTP/2 remedies that limit.)

Now, from the point of view of a Javascript application, an HTTP request is asynchronous. Meaning, Javascript will send the HTTP request to the server, and its response will arrive *sometime later.* In the meantime, Javascript can continue to work on other things, and when the HTTP response comes in, it will continue working on that. That is *asynchronous Javascript execution.* Javascript  *could* opt to wait until the HTTP response comes back, *blocking* everything else in the meantime; but that is pretty bad, since an HTTP response can take a relative eternity compared to all the other things you could get done in the meantime (like keeping the UI responsive).

Comment: Thanks a lot @deceze, So can I force to use a single HTTP connection to do all the request (after the previous response arrived) theoretically?

Comment: If you're doing one request after the other, then the browser is likely to reuse an existing TCP connection should one exist. That will still be a lot slower than doing several requests in parallel though. In your application code you don't really need to worry about this at all; the browser will manage how many parallel connections it can/will do at a time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, great answer

Answer (score 3):

Asynchronous means, you do an HTTP request, but you are not waiting until the answer arrives. You will handle it, when it arrives and are free to do other stuff in between. Meaning: You are **not blocking** your application from doing anything else.

Synchronous on the other Hand means, you do a request and wait for the answer before you do anything else. Meaning: You are **blocking** your application from doing anything else.