# Not loading the page

Tags: java, jquery, html, spring, spring-boot

When I click a button I'm supposed to go to eventpage (yes I have a template for eventpage in my templates folder). Why is it not loading?

Below are snippets of my code.

```
$('.events').on("click", function() {
    var eventName = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : '/eventpage',
        data : {'eventName' : eventName},
        success : function(data) {

        }
    });
});


@RequestMapping(value = "/eventpage")
public String eventPage(@RequestParam("eventName") String eventName, Model model) {
    for(Event e : EventRegistrationSystemApplication.events) {
        if(e.getName().equals(eventName)) {
            model.addAttribute("event", e);
            break;
        }
    }

    return "eventpage";
}
```

What's happening is the page that I'm supposed to go to is being loaded here:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS1TL.png)

Comment: from what I suspect, are you passing the 'header' & 'token' for ajax calls? To confirm, go to the your console and click on the 'eventPage' and see the 'headers' , 'preview' & 'response'. Please check and confirm. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're confusing the behavior of a synchronous request with that of an asynchronous request. This can helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/33969543/4796021

Comment: @Digvijay Sorry I'm new to this technology. Could you clarify to me what should I see at headers? Preview is blank. Response is the html code for eventpage.

Comment: @KyleOliva open the same state as your screenshot (go to network -> click on 'eventPage') see this example -> https://ibb.co/4f7CX5w

Comment: @Digvijay here it is https://ibb.co/ZSXDBpG

Comment: @KyleOliva header and token are missing. I will post an answer (this might help... or something else is also missing)

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax request you are using is actually posting a request to that url and not loading the webpage. If you wish to load the web page, use `window.location.href="/eventpage?eventName=" + eventName` in your JavaScript.

Comment: This isn't quite right.  `window.location.href="/eventpage?eventName=" + eventName`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have confused the asynchronous vs synchronous request, you could look at [this post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) to learn more. You should also use GET request to load the page (Not a POST). A Post request is usually for sending form data to the backend, while the GET request fetches data (like from an API) or loading pages (unless it's a web app).

You can do a page change as Alex Davies suggested with Javascript (not with Ajax). You can also change the @RequestMapping to [@GetMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html)("/eventpage") to use a more direct approach with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot (ibb.co/ZSXDBpG ), header and token are missing from the post call.

```
$('.events').on("click", function() {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    var eventName = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : '/eventpage',
        data : {'eventName' : eventName},
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        },
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

After the change, please check your console. Also check 'preview' and 'response'. Hope this helps!!